# Is there a method to use Google Translate to translate content with both plain text and markdown?

Tags: google-chrome, markdown, google-translate

As I'm not so good at English, I use **Google Translate** plugin to read English text, but sometimes I have problems when meeting **Markdown** text.

It happened that Google Translate can't translate them clearly, it usually doubled the content.

Just as shown below:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfOXK.png)

Is there any methods to not let the content show twice?

Much obliged !

Answer (score 0):

The content you selected in your picture is not a markdown text. It is a mathjax content.

Google Translate can't translate a math equation clearly. So, give up.

If you select it by right click, you will find it.